# How to create a reusable search bar in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, button, search

I have a working search bar that can find a tableview cell based on the data in an array but I want to know how I can make it reusable where it searches for different data based on which button is clicked or at least one button.

```
extension ViewController : UISearchBarDelegate {

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        filteredData = []
        if searchButton.isEnabled == true && searchText == "" {
            filteredData = profileNames
        }
        else {
        for users in profileNames {
            if searchButton.isEnabled == true && users.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) {
                filteredData.append(users)
            }
        }
    }
        self.TableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: You may need to clarify your question, maybe with an example of how yould like to use it.  It seems like you could achieve what you want by just varying the if conditions in your else clause above, but I'm not sure that's what you're asking?  (You could also tidy up the code by using filter, but that is mainly a style thing)

Comment: I guess you may want the search condition to be dynamic.why not use a search function as parameter and pass it the your searchbar constructor?